# Editing Gsettings unsuccesful when initiated from cron

Tags: scripts, cron, gsettings

I must have a blind spot, but I cannot find what it is.

I made a small python script that removes VLC from the sound menu. It runs perfectly in any way I run it from the terminal or from a launcher or whatever you can think of.

**What the script actually does** is nothing more than get the get the current settings:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players
```

edit the list, and set the changed list by:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players "['newlist']"
```

These commands are executed by a python script,. However, *when run from a cronjob* (`crontab -e`) only the gsettings ***- get -*** part works, but *not* the gsettings ***- set -*** section. That the *get* section works fine with cron, I checked by making the script write data (the original as well as the edited) to an external file.

**Not a python problem**

To see if the problem is related to python code, I created a bash script that applies a changed sound menu items list. The story is the same: the bash script runs fine from the command line or a launcher, *not* from cron, while any other command in the same script would run fine.
Also, if I add any command at the end of the script below, it works fine and it looks like the script is satisfied with its own work.

Why is the gsettings *set* command not working when initiated from cron?

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

def read_soundmenu():
    # read the current launcher contents
    get_menuitems = subprocess.Popen([
        "gsettings", "get", "com.canonical.indicator.sound", "interested-media-players"
        ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return eval((get_menuitems.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")))

def set_current_menu(current_list): # this takes no effect from cron
    # preparing subprocess command string
    current_list = str(current_list).replace(", ", ",")
    subprocess.Popen([
        "gsettings", "set", "com.canonical.indicator.sound", "interested-media-players",
        current_list,
        ])

current_list = read_soundmenu()
for item in current_list:
    if item == "vlc.desktop":
        current_list.remove(item)
set_current_menu(current_list)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The solution**

It turned out the blind spot was a hole in my knowledge. The reason for not running *specific* commands in the python script (`gsettings set`) was because cron uses a very restricted set of environment variables.

To run a `gsettings *set*` command from cron (in general), it takes more than just running it from your personal cron file; the environment variable *DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS* is needed for correct execution.

For reasons of convenience and flexibility, I solved it, inspired by- and based on the information in [this post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666729), by creating an "intermediate" script that both exports the variable and calls the actual script. The actual script edits `gsettings`. Since (normally) a process inherits the environment of its parent, now the script runs fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-);/path/to/script.py
```

(assuming script.py is executable)

**Including the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable in a python script**

To make editing `gsettings` possible by a python script, run by cron (and make an intermediate script unnecessary) the function below could be included in the script. It should be called before the `gsettings set` function in the script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

def set_envir():
    pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "gnome-session"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    cmd = "grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/"+pid+"/environ|cut -d= -f2-"
    os.environ["DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"] = subprocess.check_output(
        ['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd]).decode("utf-8").strip().replace("\0", "")
```

Comment: Great post Jacob. This is very helpfull too for customizing vagrant provisions.

Comment: @Wtower I am glad it is of use!

Comment: Side note: Since multiple processes can be returned by `pgrep`, you can add `PID=$(pgrep gnome-session | head-1)` to only match the first.