# Editing Gsettings from Cron via script doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, gsettings

So, I'm trying to change my theme from a light to a dark version in the evening, and vica versa in the morning. However, Gsettings doesn't work from Cron, and the solutions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/484752/478138) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666729) don't seem to work, neither do those posted in the comments below them.

This is the script Cron is executing:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable
PID=$(pgrep -o gnome-shell)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS/proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

#Change theme
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Arc-Dark'
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name 'Arc-Dark'
```

And this is the error I'm getting in dead.letter (Crons' way of logging errors):

```
grep: /proc/1098/environ: Permission denied

(process:28536): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The given address is empty


grep: /proc/1098/environ: Permission denied

(process:28811): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The given address is empty
```

I know I can use sudo -u to run the script, but I'd rather not use the root cron.

Comment: I am not sure I am the specialist on the subject, but anyone who' d  be able to answer would probably ask: *does* it work when run from the command line (not cron)?

Comment: It could be due to environ permission, it should be readable only for root (-r-------- 1 test test 0 Dec  2 19:38 environ)

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, the script works from command line, and cron executes the script correctly. If I set it to write 'lol test' to a text file, it does. The problem lies within Cron (that somehow can't call gsettings correctly).

Comment: Because the script is executed within cron's context, perhaps replacing `gsettings` with what `$(which gsettings)`resolves to ? (I doubt this will make a difference, but might be worth a try).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue running a `dconf` command from cron.  In my case I added `dbus-launch` to the beginning of my command as well as adding a variable `DISPLAY=:0` to the crontab file.

my crontab looks like this: 

`DISPLAY=:0
0 6 * * * dbus-launch /path/to/my/dconf-script`