# dconf-dump works in terminal but not in Anacron

Tags: bash, anacron

I am running the following script daily via Anacron.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! mount | grep /media/steve/6363-6333 >/dev/null
then
    dpkg --get-selections > /home/steve/package_list
    dconf dump / > dconf-settings.ini
else
    rsync /home/steve/ownCloud/Documents/De7.ods /media/steve/6363-6333/investDe7.ods
    dpkg --get-selections > /media/steve/6363-6333/package_list
    dconf dump / > /media/steve/6363-6333/dconf-settings.ini
fi
```

It works for the `rsync` and `dpkg` commands but not for the `dconf dump`. However if I run the scriopt from the commandline it works perfectly. One othe thing I noticed is that when I checked the `dconf-settings.ini` file its size was zero until I ran the script by hand

Edit: I added the full path for dconf `/usr/bin/dconf` as suggested by Jim below, and the script did run and upadate `dconf-settings.ini`. However `dconf-settings.ini` was empty, 0 bytes. When I then ran the script by hand the file was updated and had 17,2kB.

Comment: Try using full path for dconf, it is `/usr/bin/dconf`.

Comment: Ah! I will try that and report back tomorrow on whether it worked or not. I am sure it will.

Comment: I think it's more likely to be for the same reasons as here: [Editing Gsettings unsuccesful when initiated from cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483687/editing-gsettings-unsuccesful-when-initiated-from-cron). It *might* be sufficient to set `DISPLAY` rather than `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`

Comment: @Jim OK, it partly worked. The file 'dconf-settings.ini' was updated along with the others but unfortunately it was empty, 0 bytes. When I then ran the script by hand the file had 17,2kB.