# dconf in Anacron

Tags: dconf, anacron

If I run the following script as a non-su user from a terminal it works and the `dconf-settings.ini` is updated with a file size of 17.2kB. However if I run the same script in Anacron the `dconf-settings.ini` is updated but the file size is 0:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! mount | grep /media/steve/6363-6333 >/dev/null
then
    dpkg --get-selections > /home/steve/package_list
    /usr/bin/dconf dump / > dconf-settings.ini
else
    rsync /home/steve/ownCloud/Documents/investDe7.ods /media/steve/6363-6333/investDe7.ods
    dpkg --get-selections > /media/steve/6363-6333/package_list
    /usr/bin/dconf dump / > /media/steve/6363-6333/dconf-settings.ini
fi
```

I changed the $PATH in Anacron to the same as my own path. Here is the anacrontab:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly

#Steve's additions
1   15  sync.daily  /home/steve/Scripts/syncStuff
```

I posted a similar question a few days ago but this is not the same problem.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments on your previous question [dconf-dump works in terminal but not in Anacron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143088/dconf-dump-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-anacron), this may be because `dconf` has no way to attach to the session bus that is running in your desktop session.

Comment: I read your comment and the link you gave but failed to understand that conclusion. Do you mean to say that it is not possibly to automatically backup the dconf settings?